# How to download a file from S3 using Apache libcloud?

Tags: amazon-s3

I am using temporary security credentials (session token )

I am getting Invalid credetials error but the credentials are all correct(verified)
Please point my mistake in the following code

```
from libcloud.storage.types import Provider 
from libcloud.storage.providers import get_driver 
cls = get_driver(Provider.S3) 
driver = cls(access_key, secret_key, token=session_token, region=region) 
obj = driver.get_object(container_name='bucket name', object_name='s3 file path with file name')
```

I PROGRESSED WITH THE CODE

BUT THE BUCKET REGION sa-east-1 IS NOW THROWING ERROR FOR PROVIDER driver

'This bucket is located in a different region. Please use the correct driver.'>

i HAVE TRIED USING THE driver get_driver(Provider.S3_SA_EAST)
BUT NO LUCK.
any help is appreciated

Comment: Please edit the question and add your (properly formatted) code there, it's unreadable if you add it as a comment

Comment: please share code

Comment: Edited the code....